# Highest grade and name not displaying

Tags: python

I need to find the average grade for 2 students, final line should display highest grade average and the name of student. This is what I have, cannot figure out what I am missing...

```py
def main ():

    names= ("Rebecca", "Jennifer")
 
    Welcome()

    for name in names:

        grade= totalgrade(name)
        
    highestgrade()
    if (totalgrade < grade_average):
       grade_average= totalgrade
       highname=names

#----------------------------------
def Welcome():
    
    print ("Hello, this program will calculate the average grade\n")

def average(totalgrade,num):
    grade_average= totalgrade/num
    return grade_average


    discussionboard= 0.15
    quiz= 0.25
    programassignment= 0.50


def totalgrade(name):
    xyz=0
    
    print("Please enter your grades for the following assignments:", name)

        #Initialize variable
    totalgrade=0
    nullStr=""
    continueLoop= True
    num= 100
    
    cnt=1
    while(continueLoop):

         db = int(input("What was your discussion board grade?\n"))
         q = int(input("What was your quiz grade?\n"))
         pa = int(input("What was your program assignment grade?\n"))

         totalgrade= (totalgrade + (db/100)*15 + (q/100)*25 + (pa/100)*60)

         grade_average= average(totalgrade,num)*100
         
         print ("Total number of points:", totalgrade, "out of 300")
         print ("Your grade average for this course is:", grade_average, "%\n")

         return (xyz)

def highestgrade(grade_average,highname):
    highest= max(grade_average)
    
    print("The student with the hightest grade of ", highest, "is: ", highname )
        
#execute
main()
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a fixed version.

```
def main():
    names = ("Rebecca", "Jennifer")
    print_welcome()
    grades = [(total_grade(name), name) for name in names]
    print_highest_grade(grades)


def print_welcome():
    print("Hello, this program will calculate the average grade\n")


def total_grade(name):
    print("Please enter your grades for the following assignments:", name)
    db = int(input("What was your discussion board grade?\n"))
    q = int(input("What was your quiz grade?\n"))
    pa = int(input("What was your program assignment grade?\n"))

    total = (db/100)*15 + (q/100)*25 + (pa/100)*60
    
    print ("Total number of points:", total, "out of 100")
    return total


def print_highest_grade(grades):
    highest, highname = max(grades)
    print("The student with the hightest grade of", highest, "is:", highname )
        
#execute
main()
```

A lot of the code was completely pointless (e.g. anything that comes after a `return`), so I just removed it, which made what remained much simpler to debug.  As a general rule, if you're not sure what a certain piece of code is doing, you should remove it (and if need be, replace it with something that's easier to understand -- but "dead" code that does nothing at all should always just be removed and forgotten).  I was also unable to work out what the `average` function is supposed to be doing; your `totalgrade` calculation already builds a weighted average, and all you did to compute the "average" was just multiply the total by 100 and divide it by 100 again, which comes out to the same number.  So that also can be removed, which solves the problem of figuring out whether we should be counting the "total" or the "average" grade for the purposes of determining the highest grade.

The crux of what you need to fix the "highest grade" problem is to store the grades *and* names in a list.  Then you can simply take the max item from the list, and you'll have the highest grade as well as the highest name.